# Accessing Microsoft Forms 2.0 Frame Controls in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I found out that the only way to have controls be visible in a Frame in Excel is to add them with right-mouse-click Edit. But when I do this the controls are not listed in VBA.

These are the controls on the worksheet:

[image: Controls]

The first option button is optToday, the first textbox txtToday, the second option button optDate, the second textbox txtDate. The frame is groupDate, the button cmdGetWeek, the third textbox is txtWeekofMonth.

But this is all that comes up in VBA:

[image: Controls Missing]

I am looking to call a function to calculate week of month when the user clicks on the button. If the user selected today this is the date that will be sent to the function. If the user selected a different date that will will be sent instead.

What I have so far for the code is this:

```
Private Sub cmdGetWeek_Click()
Dim selectedDate As Date
Dim calcWeekNum

If (optToday.Value = True) Then
    selectedDate = txtToday.Value
Else:
    selectedDate = txtDate.Value
End If
MsgBox ("Selected: " & selectedDate)
calcWeekNum = WeekOfMonth(selectedDate) End Sub
```

I get a Run-Time Error '424' for "If (optToday.Value = True) Then".

What is the correct way of accessing the frame controls?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you added a Form Frame or an ActiveX Frame.

Form Frames are insertable, by default, from the Insert menu:

[image: Insert Menu]

In order to be able to handle control events in VBA, you need to use the ActiveX form of the Frame control... But by default, the Frame ActiveX control isn't visible on the Insert menu. You'll need to press the More Controls button:

[image]

And then choose Microsoft Forms 2.0 Frame Control from the list of controls:

[image]

You'll then need to ensure that you add the ActiveX form of the Option Buttons and other controls... All of the controls (and their events), including the Frame and the Option Buttons will then appear in the Worksheet's event drop-down.

Comment: As the title says, that's the frame I added. But the only way to add controls to that frame is as I described. But these controls are only visible in Design Mode.

Comment: Is there a chance that your Group Policy and/or Excel security settings are preventing ActiveX controls from being usable on sheets?

Comment: Controls are usable. The problem again is that the only way to use the Forms 2.0 frame is to right mouse click and add controls. The ones on the Insert ActiveX Controls won't show.